# How to get the currently executing file within powershell function

Tags: powershell

The following S.O. question addresses the problem (when you're trying to figure it out from within a script).
[How can I get the current PowerShell executing file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817198/how-can-i-get-the-current-powershell-executing-file)

How would you do it if you were within a function.

The Example below works outside the definition of the function, just not inside.

```
echo ''
echo '******** outside function scope'
echo "Path: $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)"
echo "Definition: $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"
echo '*******************************'
echo ''

function myHelper()
{
    echo '******** inside function scope'
    #EMPTY
    echo "Path: $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)"
    #Prints the string definition of the function itself
    echo "Definition: $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"
    echo '******************************'
}

myHelper
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get this info via:

```
$MyInvocation.ScriptName
```

This will return whichever script file the function was invoked from.