# Getting Script name in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Is there any other way except $MyInvocation.InvocationName in powershell to get the script name?
As i need to turn my script in an exe and in that case it doesnt work on that exe.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm assuming since you convert the powershell script to an executable that you are after the location of the executable. You can get it this way:

```
[Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()[0]
```

Comment: fwiw - if you are debugging this in ISE, the script name becomes the second parameter:  `[Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()[1]`

Comment: Try `$PSCommandPath` or `$MyInvocation.PSCommandPath` (according to this great answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43643346/5649639)

Answer (score 3):

If you want something that works within and outside of ISE you can use

```
$MyInvocation.InvocationName
```

Since full paths and .\YourScript.ps1 can be returned you can parse the name with:

```
[Regex]::Match( $MyInvocation.InvocationName, '[^\\]+\Z', [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase -bor [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::SingleLine ).Value
```

Comment: When called from within a function, `$MyInvocation.InvocationName` is the function's name.