# How to return the name of the calling script from a Powershell Module?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have two Powershell files, a module and a script that calls the module.

**Module: test.psm1**

```
Function Get-Info {
    $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
}
```

**Script: myTest.ps1**

```
Import-Module C:\Users\moomin\Documents\test.psm1 -force
Get-Info
```

When I run `./myTest.ps1` I get

`Get-Info`

I want to return the name of the calling script (test.ps1). How can I do that?

Comment: I realize that this may just be an academic exercise for you, but why not just call `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name` from the myTest.ps1 script to get that info?

Comment: It's not an academic exercise. I have posted simple example code to aid the answerer. I need to get the name of the calling script from the module.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the current PowerShell executing file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817198/how-can-i-get-the-current-powershell-executing-file)

Comment: @JohnC: This question is about calling script, other question is about executing file. E.g.if  main.ps1 calls function from module.psm1,  calling script is main.ps1, and executing sctipt is module.psm1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use PSCommandPath instead in your module:
Example test.psm1

```
function Get-Info{
    $MyInvocation.PSCommandPath
}
```

Example myTest.ps1

```
Import-Module C:\Users\moomin\Documents\test.psm1 -force
Get-Info
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\moomin\Documents\myTest.ps1
```

If you want only the name of the script that could be managed by doing

```
GCI $MyInvocation.PSCommandPath | Select -Expand Name
```

That would output:

```
myTest.ps1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does work for the PSv3+ [Module Auto-Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules?view=powershell-6#module-auto-loading) feature

Answer (score 13):

I believe you could use the [Get-PSCallStack](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849961.aspx) cmdlet, which returns an array of stack frame objects.  You can use this to identify the calling script down to the line of code.

**Module: test.psm1**

```
Function Get-Info {
    $callstack = Get-PSCallStack
    $callstack[1].Location
}
```

Output:

```
myTest.ps1: Line 2
```

Answer (score 5):

Using the $MyInvocation.MyCommand is relative to it's scope.

A simple example (Of a script located : C:\Dev\Test-Script.ps1):

```
$name = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name;
$path = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path;

function Get-Invocation(){
   $path = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path;
   $cmd = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name; 
   write-host "Command : $cmd - Path : $path";
}

write-host "Command : $cmd - Path : $path";
Get-Invocation;
```

The output when running .\c:\Dev\Test-Script.ps1 :

```
Command : C:\Dev\Test-Script.ps1 - Path : C:\Dev\Test-Script.ps1
Command : Get-Invocation - Path :
```

As you see, the $MyInvocation is relative to the scoping. If you want the path of your script, do not enclose it in a function. If you want the invocation of the command, then you wrap it.

You could also use the callstack as suggested, but be aware of scoping rules.

Answer (score 2):

To refer to the invocation info of the calling script, use:

```
@(Get-PSCallStack)[1].InvocationInfo
```

e.g.:

```
@(Get-PSCallStack)[1].InvocationInfo.MyCommand.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this today after trying a couple of techniques.

```
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$ScriptName = $MyInvocation.MyCommand | select -ExpandProperty Name
Invoke-Expression ". $Script\$ScriptName"
```

Answer (score 1):

For you googlers looking for quick copy paste solution,
here is what works in Powershell 5.1

**Inside your module:**

```
$Script = (Get-PSCallStack)[2].Command
```

This will output just the script name (`ScriptName.ps1`) which invoked a function located in module.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the automatic variable MyInvocation from the parent scope and get the name from there.

```
Get-Variable -Scope:1 -Name:MyInvocation -ValueOnly
```

I did a basic test to check to see if it would always just get the direct parent scope and it worked like a treat and is extremely fast as opposed to `Get-PSCallStack`

```
function ScopeTest () {
    Write-Information -Message:'ScopeTest'
}
Write-nLog -Message:'nLog' -Type:110 -SetLevel:Verbose
ScopeTest
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This provides the script path with trailing backslash as one variable and the script name as another.

The path works with Powershell 2.0 and 3.0 and 4.0 and probably 5.0
Where with Posershell $PSscriptroot is now available.

$_INST = $myinvocation.mycommand.path.substring(0,($myinvocation.mycommand.path.length - $MyInvocation.mycommand.name.length))

$_ScriptName = $myinvocation.mycommand.path.substring($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition.LastIndexOf('\'),($MyInvocation.mycommand.name.length +1))

$_ScriptName = $_ScriptName.TrimStart('\')

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more reusable approach, you can use:

```
function Get-CallingFileName
{
    $cStack = @(Get-PSCallStack)
    $cStack[$cStack.Length-1].InvocationInfo.MyCommand.Name
}
```

The challenge I had was having a function that could be reused within the module.  Everything else assumed that the script was calling the module function directly and if it was removed even 1 step, then the result would be the module file name.  If, however, the source script is calling a function in the module which is, in turn, calling another function in the module, then this is the only answer I've seen that can ensure you're getting the source script info.

Of course, this approach is based on what @iRon and @James posted.

Answer (score 0):

I use this in [my module](https://github.com/alekdavis/SingleInstance):

```
function Get-ScriptPath {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [string]
        $Extension = '.ps1'
    )

    # Allow module to inherit '-Verbose' flag.
    if (($PSCmdlet) -and (-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Verbose'))) {
        $VerbosePreference = $PSCmdlet.GetVariableValue('VerbosePreference')
    }

    # Allow module to inherit '-Debug' flag.
    if (($PSCmdlet) -and (-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Debug'))) {
        $DebugPreference = $PSCmdlet.GetVariableValue('DebugPreference')
    }
    
    $callstack = Get-PSCallStack

    $i = 0
    $max = 100

    while ($true) {
        if (!$callstack[$i]) {
            Write-Verbose "Cannot detect callstack frame '$i' in 'Get-ScriptPath'."
            return $null
        }

        $path = $callstack[$i].ScriptName

        if ($path) {
            Write-Verbose "Callstack frame '$i': '$path'."
            $ext = [IO.Path]::GetExtension($path)
            if (($ext) -and $ext -eq $Extension) {
                return $path
            }
        }

        $i++

        if ($i -gt $max) {
            Write-Verbose "Exceeded the maximum of '$max' callstack frames in 'Get-ScriptPath'."
            return $null
        }
    }

    return $null
}
```