Powershell path function not working for ps1 called from ps1
1st ps1:
#$dll = 'C:\Some\Path\To\dll'

$dll = $PSScriptRoot+'\dll'
Write-Host $dll -foreground Green
 
$code = @"
Some code that works
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp -ReferencedAssemblies $dll
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($dll)

[HelloWorld.Program]::Main()

2nd ps1:
$job = Start-Job -FilePath "Myps1.ps1" -Name "aaa"

$dll = $PSScriptRoot+'\Mydll.dll'
Write-Host $dll -foreground Yellow

Start-Sleep 5

$JobStatus = $job.State
Write-Host $job.State -foreground Yellow

if ($JobStatus -like "Running")
    {
        Write-Host "Gresit" -foreground Red
    }
else 
    {
        Write-Host "Corect" -foreground Green
    }

I am calling the first ps1 from the 2nd ps1.
The problem arises because when calling the first ps1 from the 2nd, if I use
$dll = 'C:\Some\Path\To\dll'

then the program works. But if I use
$dll = $PSScriptRoot+'\dll'

then the program does nothing.
Needless to say that if I call the first ps1 it works with both versions of dll path.

What is the value of $PSScriptRoot in the second script (use write-host “script root = ‘$PSScriptRoot’” to find out) , and what do you expect it to be?

I am expecting it to be the relative path to my source file. when running it it is printing the correct path to my ps1.

Can you show the literal values of $PSScriptRoot - current and expected? Please remember the people who read your question can't see your screen so you need to provide specific technical details in your question. even if they seem obvious to you

C:\Users\Admin\Documents\PowerShell Scripts

that is the value of $PSScriptRoot and the value of the expected path

In every single case $PSScriptRoot is behaving very well

I know it to be working correctly because when I run the first script by itself it works but when I run it from the 2nd script it does nothing. The c# code does nothing :(

You mean that the value of $PSScriptRoot is always correct? Even when you call it from the second script?

@OcasoProtal - I suspect the $PSScriptRoot inside script 1 is $null or undefined when calling it from Start-Job in script 2, and the OP is providing ambiguous facts - Start-Job runs the file as a scriptblock, not a script and scriptblocks don't have $PSScriptRoot defined...

thank you, this helped me very much in understanding my problem. so a walkaround would be sending parameters to the function, but this seems so hard doing  esp inside a Start-Job

Ocaso Protal yes, this is what I mean

So this is your problem...
$job = Start-Job -FilePath "Myps1.ps1" -Name "aaa"

If you look at the documentation for the -FilePath parameter of Start-Job it says:

-FilePath
When you use this parameter, PowerShell converts the contents of the specified script file to a script block and runs the script block as a background job.

So your code is sort-of equivalent to:
$src = Get-Content "Myps1.ps1"
$sb  = [scriptblock]::Create($src)
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $sb -Name "aaa"

And if we run a near-identical cut-n-pasteable example:
$src = @"
write-host "root = '$PSScriptRoot'"
"@
$sb = [scriptblock]::Create($src)
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $sb -Name "aaa"

Wait-Job $job
Receive-Job $job

We see the following output:
root = ''

That is because $PSScriptRoot is not defined when running inside a ScriptBlock, only when running as a script:

$PSScriptBlock
Contains the full path of the executing script's parent directory.
In PowerShell 2.0, this variable is valid only in script modules (.psm1). Beginning in PowerShell 3.0, it's valid in all scripts.

A ScriptBlock is an in-memory object, so it doesn't have a "parent directory", and creating a ScriptBlock from the contents of a file doesn't persist the file path into the ScriptBlock, so $PSScriptRoot is undefined in both cases.
This answer gives some more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72026978/3156906
And a suggested workaround there is to make the call to Start-Job a simple wrapper around the Call operator to invoke your script, because then your script executes as a script (not a scriptblock) and has access to the $PSScriptBlock automatic variable:
$sb = { & ".\first.ps1" }
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $sb -Name "aaa"

$result = Wait-Job $job
Receive-Job $job

So the script file runs as a script, not a scriptblock, and it has a $PSScriptRoot automatic variable available as a result, which results in this output:
C:\src\so\root\dll


thank you so much. I am now understanding my problem a lot better <3

np. feel free to mark as the answer if it solves your problem.
