# Getting the first argument passed to the cli

Tags: powershell, arguments, command-line-interface

Trying just to write a simple script that would return the SHA256 signature of a file using the file name passed to my ps1 script :

The scriptname is `sha256sum.ps1`.

The first argument will be any file, example :

```
sha256sum.ps1 dummy.exe
```

I tried these inside `sha256sum.ps1` :

```
Get-FileHash -algo SHA256 %1
Get-FileHash -algo SHA256 $1
Get-FileHash -algo SHA256 $args[1]
```

but none of them worked.

Is there a simple way to do that ?

EDIT : Here is the final version of my script thanks to your help, guys :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env pwsh
param( $firstArg )

function calcSignature( $filename ) {
    $scriptName = Split-Path -Leaf $PSCommandPath
    switch( $scriptName ) {
        "md5sum.ps1"    { $algo = "MD5";    Break }
        "sha1sum.ps1"   { $algo = "SHA1";   Break }
        "sha256sum.ps1" { $algo = "SHA256"; Break }
        "sha384sum.ps1" { $algo = "SHA384"; Break }
        "sha512sum.ps1" { $algo = "SHA512"; Break }
    }
    (Get-FileHash -algo $algo $filename).Hash + "  " + $filename
}

calcSignature( $firstArg )
```

Now I only have one script and the others are links pointing to `sha256sum.ps1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're looking for *"How to pass an argument to your `.ps1` script"*.

This is an example of how the script **`sha256sum.ps1`** would look:

```
param(
    [parameter(mandatory)]
    [validatescript({
        Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf
    })]
    [system.io.fileinfo]$File
)

(Get-FileHash $File -Algorithm SHA256).Hash
```

Now, if we were to call this script, as an example:

```
PS \> .\sha256sum.ps1 .\test.html
1B24ED8C7929739D296DE3C5D6695CA40D8324FBF2F0E981CF03A8A6ED778C9C
```

**Note**: the current directory is where the script and the html file are located, if that was not the case, you should use the absolute path.

---

I would recommend you to the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.1) to get a concept on functions and the `param(...)` block.

Answer (score 2):

[Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69845678/45375) shows how you to properly *declare parameters* for your script, which is generally preferable.

As for **what you tried**:

The [automatic **`$args`** variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) contains arguments not bound to any declared parameters. In other words: if your script doesn't declare any parameters, `$args` is the only way to access any arguments that were passed.

The **first argument is at index `0`**, not `1`.

Note:

- This differs from other shells / programming language where the element at index `0` reflects the script / program being called.

  - To get the full path of the enclosing script in PowerShell, use the [automatic `$PSCommandPath` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pscommandpath).
- Thus, for instance, `%1` in a batch file and `$1` in a `bash` script - both of which contain the *first argument* - correspond to `$args[0]` in PowerShell.

Therefore, `Get-FileHash -algo SHA256 $args[0]` should have worked.

Comment: @SebMa, I thought so. I've updated the answer to address the potential confusion more explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. Is there another command to get the script name without the path ?

Comment: @SebMa, use `Split-Path -Leaf $PSCommandPath`

Comment: @SebMa `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name` can work too

Comment: @Santiago-Squarzon `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name` returns the function name when called from inside a function.

Comment: @SebMa that's right, but given that you were calling the script externally and not using a function, it would return the script name in that case.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon You're right. But I have the habit of re-using my code. So if I don't want to get into trouble later when writing functions. I think I'll stick to the `$PSCommandPath` variable which seems the most reliable since PS3.0 according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43643346/5649639).

Comment: @mklement0 How'bout (`%*` or `$@`) and `argc` ? Is there any equivalent ? Do you have any documentation on their equivalent ?

Comment: @SebMa, `$args` is the array of _all_ unbound arguments, and as such it is the analog of `%*` and `$@`. The answer already links to the documentation for `$args`. If by `argc` you mean the _count_ of arguments, simply use `$args.Count`.

Comment: @mklement0 In the meantime I found `$args.Length`, is this the same as `$args.Count` ?

Comment: @SebMa. Yes, they're the same. `.Length` is the type-native property. `.Count` is provided via the `ICollection` interface. `.Count` is preferable for consistency, because most collection types have only a `.Count` property.